# How does VS 2017 determine .NET Standard dependencies from Paket?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, paket

I have a proof-of-concept solution that has a .NET Standard project in it. I use [Paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/) to manage my nuget dependencies. I am able to use `paket add` and `dotnet restore`, [per these instructions](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/paket-and-dotnet-cli.html), to add a nuget dependency to that project. When I reopen my solution, I see that a `paket.references` file has been added to that project, and that a "NuGet" section has been added under the project's "Dependencies" section in "Solution Explorer".

**I'm curious, how does VS2017 know what dependencies to list that "NuGet" section?**

From the instructions I linked to above:

> In contrast to traditional .NET projects Paket will not add assembly
>   references to your project files. Instead it will only generate a
>   single line:
>
> `<Import Project="..\..\.paket\Paket.Restore.targets" />`
>
> This hook tells the .NET SDK to restore packages via Paket's restore
>   mechanism. A nice benefit is that your project files are now much
>   cleaner and don't contain many assembly references.

I'm sure I'm missing something, but I don't see anything in `Paket.Restore.targets` that would tell Visual Studio where to look to find the dependency chain of the nuget package I added to the project. There are no direct references to any dependencies mentioned in the project file.

For context, I have a repo where I'm trying to add a .NET Standard project to a solution that is full of .NET Framework projects. I'm running into an issue where `paket add` seems to correctly create a `paket.references` file for the new project, but `dotnet restore` doesn't seem to be causing the project references to update, resulting in my project not having a reference to the nuget dependency I'm trying to have it reference. I'm having trouble creating a reproducible example (my proof-of-concept seems to be working fine), so I'm trying to better understand how this infrastructure works to help with debugging.

Comment: This is a good question. I think paket is broken in some ways. When i add a paket.references, and do a install, update etc (i dont know what to do to make the references actually work) i get nothing. It is so undocumented. I like the features, but I cant see how i should use this when i cant even add references to my project :)